# Какие данные можно узнать из QR кода на чеке?

Tags: qrcode, qr

возник такой вопрос: Какие данные можно узнать из QR кода чека?(При этом не ссылаясь на налоговую)
К примеру там есть данные о времени, цене, фп, фд и фн. Можно ли из последних 3 узнать какой-нибудь индификатор компании?(желательно привязанный к определенному магазину, а не сети)

```
t=20190402T203500&s=800.00&fn=8710000100247007&i=119800&fp=4030914807&n=1
```

Comment: Запрос с этими данными в веб-сервис ФНС поможет узнать как минимум ИНН.

Comment: @free_ze, для это данные о чеке должны уже быть в ФНС или можно и без этого посмотреть ИНН через нее?

Comment: Наверное они сразу в ФНС должны попадать. На Хабре была [статья](https://habr.com/en/post/358966/) как вытаскивать у них данные.

Comment: я находил API, но как раз суть в том, что чеки не всегда сразу попадают в базу. К примеру может не быть хорошего соединения, в таких случаях может быть задержка около дня.